# How to prevent from alphabetically sorting in azure logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

It has been automatically sorting in azure logic apps when I saved my logic flow.

[I want to set the first item to `id` as like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLWQ9.png)

[But, I got like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49xPw.png)

[cosmosDB's result document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVTJF.png)

Comment: I dont think you can do anything about it, is it really a problem ? I understand that it can bother you but it is not such a big deal :-)

Comment: HaHa...Yeah, it is not problem to my resource and just only be sensitive to appearance. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the JSON standard, properties in an object are not ordered and usually JavaScript JSON libraries default to alphabetical ordering of properties.

So this is an expected behaviour that shouldn't have side effects if you stick to the JSON format. In other scenarios, like converting to XML, this might be an issue.

HTH.